# ¿Cómo comparar data de un array que pertenece a un campo de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo la siguiente data en un JSON

```json
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ASTRID",
            "schedule": ["MO10:00-12:00","TU10:00-12:00",
            "TH01:00-03:00","SA14:00-18:00","SU20:00- 21:00"]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "RENE",
            "schedule":["MO10:00-12:00","TH12:00-14:00","SU20:00-21:00"]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "ANDRES",
            "schedule": ["MO10:00-12:00","TH12:00-14:00","SU20:00-21:00"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Y debo obtener qué usuarios tienen el mismo horario, por ejemplo `ASTRID-RENE 2`
Hacerlo con arrays separados no es problema, pero cuando tengo la data así no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Mi código:

```javascript
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get('assets/json/data.json').subscribe((data) => {
        this.jsonDataResult = data;
        console.log('DATA : ', this.jsonDataResult);
        if(JSON.stringify(this.jsonDataResult.name) === 
            JSON.stringify(this.jsonDataResult.name)){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.jsonDataResult.name))
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No sé exactamente la igualdad que quieres filtrar, si tienen que tener todos los elementos de schedule igual, o que por lo menos coincida 1 o que tengan el mismo que le pases por una variable.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que una opción puede ser reagrupar el objeto en función de `schedule`:

```js
const obj = {"employees":[{"id":1,"name":"ASTRID","schedule":["MO10:00-12:00","TU10:00-12:00","TH01:00-03:00","SA14:00-18:00","SU20:00- 21:00"]},{"id":2,"name":"RENE","schedule":["MO10:00-12:00","TH12:00-14:00","SU20:00-21:00"]},{"id":3,"name":"ANDRES","schedule":["MO10:00-12:00","TH12:00-14:00","SU20:00-21:00"]}]};


const res = obj.employees.reduce((p, c) => {

  c.schedule.forEach(h => {// <-- Recorremos el schedule de cada elemento de employees 

    if (h in p) {// <-- Si el horario exite previamente en el acumulador

      p[h].push(c.name);// <-- Agregamos el nombre  

    } else {// <-- Si no existe previamente

      p[h] = [c.name];// <-- Creamos la fecha y le agregamos el nombre dentro de un array

    }

  });

  return p;

}, {});// <-- Finalizado esto, estan todas las fechas con todos los nombres asociados

for (h in res) {// <-- Recorremos el objeto previamete creado

  if (res[h].length < 2) {
    delete res[h];// <-- Eliminamos del objeto todos los elementos que tengan menos de 2 nombres
  }else{
    res[h] = res[h].join("-")// <-- Los demas los unimos con un -
  }

}

console.log(res);
```

Luego si necesitas filtras los horarios con mas de una persona. Dicho sea de paso, idealmente, en mi opinión las fechas y horarios deberían ser de tipo `Date`.

Comment: Emmeus, leyendo tu respuesta me doy cuenta que había entendido mal el problema y no respondí a la pregunta. Muy buena tu solución. Hay un punto muy pequeño que creo que suma de lo que dije, y es que entiendo que Alex confunde el JSON que recibe (texto) del objeto que vos estás usando. Yo aclararía que para obtener el obj que usas al principio debe hacer var obj = JSON.stringify(this.jsonDataResult)

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por tu ayuda el metodo reduce se que simplifica todo a uno solo, pero no logro comprender algunas cosas de  tu solución. Gracias otra vez

Comment: Me ayudarías a entenderlo mejor por favor

Comment: @Alex Agregué unos comentarios para que se entenda paso a paso, para el funcionamiento general de reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: te lo agradezco muchas  gracias voy a estudiarlo

Answer (score 0):

Al responder entendí mal la pregunta y contesté otra cosa, dejo parte de la respuesta porque creo que sirve. El resto lo borro, mira la respuesta de Emeeus que es la correcta.

Veo dos problemas en esta instrucción:

```
this.jsonDataResult.name
```

1. this.jsonDataResult es un string, por lo que no podes accederlo como si fuera un objeto
2. Si fuera un objeto, sería un array, por lo que deberías accederlo por índice [0] antes de acceder al name

Lo correcto es que primero lo conviertas en un objeto

```
var employees = JSON.stringify(this.jsonDataResult)
```

Luego podes acceder al contenido, por ejemplo:

```
employees[0].name
```

Cómo decía más arriba, mira la otra respuesta que es la correcta.